# How to send continuous stream of data from one iDevice to another.

Tags: ios, objective-c

Which exact topics do I need to do research on in order for me to do something simple as: sending live finger sliding data co-ordinates across the screen to another iOS device over the internet and vice versa?

Take two clients, how can I create a live connection between the two so that when user A, slides his finger across his screen user B should then be able to see where user A is sliding his finger in the form of a dot for example, that too live and vice versa when user B slides his finger across on his iDevice.

A tutorial would be great.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Can you make your question more specific? Confused on if you're asking about how to put up a server, or how to structure the data that is sent back and forth.

Comment: Hey, thanks for writing. I only require a simple answer that will allow me to send a continuous stream of data from one device to another over the internet. I have a server up and running, my code is up and running to ready to transmit the coordinates of screen `sliding` values to the other device but I dont know where to begin to begin programming this final step. Pointing me in the right direction will be helpful to me. Thank you

Comment: You definitely want to learn more about LongPolling and WebSockets. I've used these methods in numerous applications and they've all proven to be great. 

WebSockets has been a bit of a battery killer, but that just means the connection needs to be managed a little better.

Comment: @tambykojak give me one second, and i'll show you exactly what it is im trying to recreate to increase my knowledge base. Give me two seconds and I'll post a link to a video

Comment: @tambykojak This is exactly what I am trying to recreate so that I can expand myknowldge, please watch from 0.35 to 0.52 seconds. The thumbKiss feature is the simplest of things to create instead of the drawing feature. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSRLduGRoRQ

Comment: After seeing that I think it would be better to go with WebSockets.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for WebSockets that would allow me to get close to receiving data coordinates, the rest I could do myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TCP or UDP IP networking and send the data across in some form that each end can recognize. The easiest way I've found to deal with that in iOS is to use GCDAsyncSocket, a 3rd-party library you can download. The difficult part is that you cannot send the data directly between two iPhones across the Internet, as opposed to across the LAN, without a relay server (which you would need to program) in between unless you use some kind of NAT transversal.

And, of course, you'll need to know Cocoa Touch (AKA iOS programming).

Comment: I have a server up and running where I can install modules as they are required depending on what technologies I need to have setup. I am mainly asking which topics I would need to cover for me to be able to transmit a continous stream of data. Does GCDAsyncSocket have anything to do with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a continuous stream. If you send data over TCP/IP repeatedly with almost no delay, the host will most likely receive it as a continuous stream of data, meaning that you need to separate it with a terminating character or use a fixed length. GCDAsyncSocket makes it easy to do with "send" and "readDataToData" functions; it handles the threading itself and takes a delegate. UDP is probably better for what you are doing because it will have better performance, and GCDAsyncUdpSocket (in that same library) handles those.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to recreate so that I can expand myknowldge, please watch from 0.35 to 0.52 seconds. The thumbKiss feature is the simplest of things to create instead of the drawing feature. http://youtube.com/watch?v=SSRLduGRoRQ

Comment: I'm assuming it's sending the thumbprint's location to the other end repeatedly. I would check the finger's location a certain number of times per second, each time sending a message containing its location over the network to the other iPhone. UDP would be faster, but the packets may be dropped or received in the wrong order. If you choose UDP over TCP, you need to research how to deal with that. On the networking software side, I still think GCDAsyncSocket (aka CocoaAsyncSocket) is the easiest and overall best library for iOS, and you should look into that.